# set "EDIT" text instead of image in icon of textfield

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have an icon in my textfield that says "EDIT". I can only set an image in icon of textfield. I want to ask if I can put a string in the icon or not..

Comment: You can use rightView property and provide button with image and text

Comment: Yes you can put string with icon if you use button in right or left view of textfield. Using right or left view is fine if you are not going to localize the app

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
emailField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

(Default `leftViewMode` is `Never`)

Updated Code version for 'Swift 4' :

```
emailField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always

emailField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Hope this helps you :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIButton` and use it as `leftView` of the textfield

```
let editBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
editBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 4, bottom: 4, right: 4)
editBtn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
editBtn.setTitle("EDIT", for: .normal)
editBtn.sizeToFit()

textField.leftViewMode = .always
textField.leftView = editBtn
```